# how can I talk to a blazeds endpoint without flash

Tags: java, javascript, blazeds

i would like to reuse my existing blazeds/java/spring apps to write some html 5 clients. Is anyone aware of a pure js (no swf bridge allowed) client that has pub/sub capability

so far my googling has found 2 projects -  **jsasmf** (which uses a tiny swf) and **amf.js** which is missing pub/sub, but no other projects besides these 2

any ideas (crazy is fine) on how to do this appreciated

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not annotate your blazeds service object implementation with [jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) annotations to expose it as a rest service. It should be possible to expose the same service through blazeds and rest at the same time. You could use [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Getting-Started-with-the-samples) to implement pub/sub

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible with another server.  You would consume the service with flash on that server and expose its api with web sockets (for example) to other clients.  Your clients would not need flash installed.

Answer (score 0):

Extending on Erik Martino's answer... you could try compiling a Java AMF client to JavaScript yourself using GWT.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party but is seems Adobe has a JS Client too. I you download the trail of Dataservices ES 4.6 its in the resource folder. A tutorial can be found [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dataservicesjee/4.6/Developing/WS74a1cc3271d4c9821a4a3ad3132cc2454ba-8000.html)

Comment: Also this JS lib works great. I have forked it to work better with BlazeDS. Didn't write, it only modified it a little. https://github.com/dsworldtrip/amfjs