# How to use Blaze DS software for angular 2?

Tags: java, angular, apache-flex, blazeds

Blaze DS enables Flex to invoke remote Java methods. It supports translation of object returned from the server into corresponding action-script object and conversion of action-script object to java object as method argument.More details:
https://dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-blazeds

How can I use it for angular-Java which can automatically map angular type-script object to java bean object while making a server call. It can avoid hassle of converting json-string to Java Bean Object and vice versa.

I have got the following by googling on  SO:
[how can I talk to a blazeds endpoint without flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11804619/how-can-i-talk-to-a-blazeds-endpoint-without-flash)

Still looking for more information on the same.

Comment: @Downvoter Please mention the reason for downvoting so that I can improve my question

Comment: Not the downvoter but asking for software recommendations is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Comment: The [help/on-topic] says very clearly that questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries, books, tutorials or other off-site resources are off-topic here.

Comment: @Lexi I want to know if such a technology exists for angular

Comment: That's still off-topic as both me and @KenWhite mentioned.

Comment: No, you don't want to know if it exists. If someone says *Yes, it exists*, you're going to want to know what it's called and where to find it, and that makes this question off-topic, as the [help/on-topic] says and I mentioned in my last comment. Off-topic means you cannot ask it here.

Comment: @Lexi So how do I ask this ? Please help me on this. The third point on that help center link suggests that I can ask about tools that are commonly used by developers.

Comment: That point is specifically about how to use tools that are commonly used by developers like an IDE. It does not allow recommendations for tools commonly used by developers because that would go against the close reason. It really boils down to that SO is not the place to ask your particular question. If the research online isn't that great or if you really are looking for professional recommendations, you should try somewhere like a subreddit in Reddit or a more discussion-based software development community.

Comment: You can't stop reading just because you found something that might make your point. Continue reading that page, particularly the section right below those bullets that says **Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:** in **bold**, and then contains a numbered list of items. See specifically item #4 in that numbered list.

Comment: @Ken White In that point it is mentioned to discuss what has been done so far, but I am still analyzing the technology to start. Its not that I haven't done any research so far. Because I didn't get any appropriate searches on Google I came here and asked this question out of curiosity. Moreover, it is a generic question related to the technology not specific to my project.

Comment: You're not reading. You keep picking and choosing the individual portions you want to see and ignoring the rest. Start with the first sentence, which says *Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.* Find a way to phrase it differently, so that it isn't asking for recommendation. Arguing about it isn't going to magically change anything; as written now, it is off-topic. Restate the question.

Comment: Much better. :-) Thanks, and vote retracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think question still makes sense to Java/Flex developers. Flex had AMF binary serialization protocol and there was excellent BlazeDS java implementation which was really convenient to use.

Angular is limited to web standards: XML/JSON/Text/... data over HTTP protocol or WebSocket, so the answer is No.